# Convert a PDF with images to text

Tags: python, image, pdfminer, pypdf

I would like to convert pdf files containing images and text to text file.
I can only do this for pdf files without text, using pdf miner, pytesseract, etc.
However, I get very bad results when my pdf document contains images.

Concretely I try to extract only the text of these pdf documents, ignoring the images which do not interest me.

Let me show you what I have already done :

```
import pytesseract as pt
from PIL import Image
import sys 

def convert(name):
    pages = convert_from_path(name, dpi=200)
    for idx,page in enumerate(pages):
        page.save('page'+str(idx)+'.jpg', 'JPEG')
        quote = Image.open('page'+str(idx)+'.jpg')
        text = pt.image_to_string(quote, lang="fra")
        file_ex = open('page'+str(idx)+'.text',"w")
        file_ex.write(text)
        file_ex.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert(sys.argv[1])
```

Has anyone already covered this subject or have some ideas?